# No sdcard folder on my emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I tried writing to the sdcard folder using the emulator, with no success, although few weeks ago it worked. I get the sdcard folder, in my app, using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. So I opened Android Device Monitor and I see no sdcard folder. I see a file with the name sdcard in my root folder and one in the mnt/ folder.
What is wrong?

The problem I am facing is not only that I do not see the sdcard but rather that I can not create a folder in it. I thought that if I solve the problem of not seeing it it will solve my main issue. Here is my code where `isPresesnt` returns false.

I also made sure that I have permission to write to the external storage.

It seems that the problem exists only with the emulator - I just tested it on my phone and it worked fine.

I also noticed that if I connect my phone to my computer while the emulator is opened, I do see the sdcard folder in the Android Device Monitor, but I do not know to which device it belongs to.

**my code**

```
    File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documents");
    boolean isPresent = true;
    if (!path.exists()) {
        isPresent = path.mkdir();
    }
```

**MANIFEST**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**permission code**

```
            perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually we cannot see SD card folder on our emulator, but it still exist in mnt/sdcard like what you mention above. If you want to see it, just import an image to that folder and it with appear in Gallery with folder name sdcard.

Comment: The problem I am facing is not only that I do not see the sdcard but rather that I can not create a folder in it. I thought that if I solve the problem of not seeing it it will solve my main issue. Here is my code

Comment: Can you try to put "/" after "/Document"? I mean your file will like this : Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documents/"

Comment: anyway, you have to restart your emulator to see that folder :D

Comment: Using "/Documents/" did not help/ Still can not make folder in sdcard. Also restarting the emulator did not help. As I mentioned in my post, it works on the real phone but not on the emulator. Could it be a bug?